# PL/SQL : Need to compare data for every field in a table in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, associative-array

I need to create a procedure which will take collection as an input and compare the data with staging table data row by row for every field (approx 50 columns).

Business logic :

1. whenever a staging table column value will mismatch with the corresponding collection variable value then i need to update **'FAIL'** into staging table STATUS column and reason into REASON column for that row.
2. If matched then need to update **'SUCCESS'** in STATUS column.

Payload will be approx 500 rows in each call.

I have created below sample script:

**PKG Specification :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE process_data
IS
TYPE pass_data_rec
IS
  record
  (
    p_eid employee.eid%type,
    p_ename employee.ename%type,
    p_salary employee.salary%type,
    p_dept employee.dept%type 
  );

type p_data_tab IS TABLE OF pass_data_rec INDEX BY binary_integer;
PROCEDURE comp_data(inpt_data IN p_data_tab);
END;
```

**PKG Body:**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE
    PACKAGE body process_data
    IS
    PROCEDURE comp_data (inpt_data IN p_data_tab)
    IS
      status VARCHAR2(10);
      reason VARCHAR2(1000);
      cnt1   NUMBER;
      v_eid employee_copy.eid%type;
      v_ename employee_copy.ename%type;
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1..inpt_data.count
      LOOP
        SELECT ec1.eid,ec1.ename,COUNT(*) over () INTO v_eid,v_ename,cnt1
        FROM employee_copy ec1
        WHERE ec1.eid = inpt_data(i).p_eid;
        IF cnt1 > 0 THEN
          IF (v_eid=inpt_data(i).p_eid AND v_ename = inpt_data(i).p_ename) THEN
            UPDATE employee_copy SET status = 'SUCCESS' WHERE eid = inpt_data(i).p_eid;
          ELSE
            UPDATE employee_copy SET status = 'FAIL' WHERE eid = inpt_data(i).p_eid;
          END IF;
        ELSE
          NULL;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
      status :='success';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      status:= 'fail';
      --reason:=sqlerrm;
    END;
    END;
```

But in this approach i have below mentioned issues.

1. Need to declare all local variables for each column value.
2. Need to compare all variable data using 'and' operator. Not sure whether it is correct way or not because if there are 50 columns then if condition will become very heavy.

   `IF (v_eid=inpt_data(i).p_eid AND v_ename = inpt_data(i).p_ename) THEN`
3. Need to update REASON column when any column data mismatched (first mismatched column name) for that row, in this approach i am not able to achieve.

Please suggest any other good way to achieve this requirement.

**Edit :**

There is only one table at my end i.e target table. Input will come from any other source as collection object.

Comment: How big are the fields?  I would concatenate all the field values along with the column name into one big string per row, then compare that.

Comment: ¿Why input is a collection?¿source table is on the same data base?

Comment: @alvalongo No. there is no source table. Input will come from ICS end. They will call this procedure by passing multiple rows in the form of collection.

Answer (score 1):

**REVISED Answer**  
You could load the the records into t temp table, but unless you want additional processing it's not necessary. AFAIK there is no way to identify the offending column (first one only) without slugging through column-by-column. However, your other concern having to declare a variable is not necessary. You can declare a single variable defined as [%rowtype](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/rowtype_attribute.htm#LNPLS01342) which gives you access to each column by name.  
 
  
Looping through an array of data to find the occasional error is just bad (imho) with SQL available to eliminate the good ones in one fell swoop. And it's available here.  Even though your input is a array we can use as a table by using the TABLE operator, which allows an array (collection) as though it were a database table. So the MINUS operator can till be employed. The following routine will set the appropriate status and  identify the first miss matched column for each entry in the input array. It reverts to your original definition in package spec, but replaces the comp_data procedure.

```
create or replace package body process_data
is
    procedure comp_data (inpt_data in p_data_tab)
    is
      -- define local array to hold status and reason for ecah.
      type status_reason_r is record
           ( eid    employee_copy.eid%type 
           , status employee_copy.status%type
           , reason employee_copy.reason%type
           );          
      type status_reason_t is
           table of status_reason_r
           index by pls_integer;
      status_reason status_reason_t := status_reason_t();

      -- define error array to contain the eid for each that have a mismatched column  
      type error_eids_t is table of employee_copy.eid%type ;
      error_eids error_eids_t; 
      current_matched_indx pls_integer;

      /*
        Helper function to identify 1st mismatched column in error row.
        Here is where we slug our way through each column to find the first column
        value mismatch. Note: There is actually validate the column sequence, but 
        for purpose here we'll proceed in the input data type definition.
      */
      function identify_mismatch_column(matched_indx_in pls_integer)
        return varchar2
      is
          employee_copy_row employee_copy%rowtype;
          mismatched_column employee_copy.reason%type;
      begin
          select * 
            into employee_copy_row
            from employee_copy
           where employee_copy.eid = inpt_data(matched_indx_in).p_eid;

          -- now begins the task of finding the mismatched column.
          if employee_copy_row.ename !=  inpt_data(matched_indx_in).p_ename
          then 
             mismatched_column := 'employee_copy.ename';
          elsif employee_copy_row.salary !=  inpt_data(matched_indx_in).p_salary 
          then  
             mismatched_column := 'employee_copy.salary';
          elsif employee_copy_row.dept !=  inpt_data(matched_indx_in).p_dept 
          then 
             mismatched_column := 'employee_copy.dept'; 
         -- elsif continue until ALL columns tested
          end if; 

          return  mismatched_column;

      exception
          -- NO_DATA_FOUND is the one error that cannot actually be reported in the customer_copy table.
          -- It occurs when an eid exista in the input data but does not exist in customer_copy.
          when NO_DATA_FOUND 
          then 
              dbms_output.put_line( 'Employee (eid)=' 
                                  || inpt_data(matched_indx_in).p_eid
                                  || ' does not exist in employee_copy table.'
                                  );
              return 'employee_copy.eid ID is NOT in table';
      end identify_mismatch_column;

      /*   
        Helper function to find specified eid in the initial inpt_data array
        Since the resulting array of mismatching eid derive from a select without sort
        there is no guarantee the index values actually match. Nor can we sort to build 
        the error array, as there is no way to know the order of eid in the initial array.
        The following helper identifies the index value in the input array for the specified 
        eid in error.
      */
      function match_indx(eid_in employee_copy.eid%type)
        return pls_integer
      is
          l_at        pls_integer := 1;
          l_searching boolean     := true;
      begin
          while l_at <= inpt_data.count
          loop 
             exit when eid_in = inpt_data(l_at).p_eid;
             l_at := l_at + 1; 
          end loop; 
          if l_at > inpt_data.count
          then  
             raise_application_error( -20199, 'Internal error: Find index for ' || eid_in ||' not found');
          end if; 
          return l_at;
      end match_indx;


    -- Main     
    begin
      -- initialize status table for each input enter 
      -- additionally this results is a status_reason table in a 1:1 with the input array.
      for i in 1..inpt_data.count
      loop
        status_reason(i).eid    := inpt_data(i).p_eid;
        status_reason(i).status :='SUCCESS';
      end loop;

      /*
         We can assume the majority of data in the input array is valid meaning the columns match.
         We'll eliminate all value rows by selecting each and then MINUSing those that do match on 
         each column. To accomplish this cast the input with TABLE function allowing it's use in SQL.
         Following produces an array of eids that have at least 1 column mismatch.
      */        
      select p_eid
        bulk collect into error_eids 
        from (select p_eid, p_ename, p_salary, p_dept from TABLE(inpt_data) 
              minus
              select eid, ename, salary, dept from employee_copy
             )  exs;

      /*
         The error_eids array now contains the eid for each miss matched data item.
         Mark the status as failed, then begin the long hard process of identifying 
         the first column causing the mismatch.
         The following loop used the nested functions to slug the way through. 
         This keeps the main line logic clear.
      */
      for i in 1 .. error_eids.count  -- if all inpt_data rows match then count is 0, we bypass the enttire loop
      loop
         current_matched_indx                       := match_indx(error_eids(i)); 
         status_reason(current_matched_indx).status := 'FAIL';
         status_reason(current_matched_indx).reason := identify_mismatch_column(current_matched_indx);
      end loop; 

      -- update employee_copy with appropriate status for each row in the input data.
      -- Except for any cid that is in the error eid table but doesn't exist in the customer_copy table.
      forall i in inpt_data.first .. inpt_data.last 
          update employee_copy
             set status = status_reason(i).status
               , reason = status_reason(i).reason
           where eid = inpt_data(i).p_eid;

    end comp_data;
end process_data;
```

There are a couple other techniques used you may want to look into if you are not familiar with them:

1. Nested Functions. There are 2 functions defined and used in the procedure.
2. Bulk Processing. That is Bulk Collect and Forall.

Good Luck.

**ORIGINAL Answer**  
It is NOT necessary to compare each column nor build a string by concatenating. As you indicated comparing 50 columns becomes pretty heavy. So let the DBMS do most of the lifting. Using the [MINUS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator does exactly what you need.

> ... the MINUS operator, which returns only unique rows returned by the
>   first query but not by the second.

Using that this task needs only 2 Updates: 1 to mark "fail", and 1 to mark "success". So try:

```
create table e( e_id integer
              , col1 varchar2(20)
              , col2 varchar2(20)
              ); 
create table stage ( e_id integer
                   , col1 varchar2(20)
                   , col2 varchar2(20)
                   , status varchar2(20)
                   , reason varchar2(20)
                   );

-- create package spec and body
create or replace package process_data
is   
    procedure comp_data;
end process_data; 

create or replace package body process_data
is
    package body process_data   
    procedure comp_data 
    is
    begin  
        update stage 
           set status='failed'
             , reason='No matching e row'
         where e_id in ( select e_id 
                          from (select e_id, col1, col2 from stage
                                except
                                select e_id, col1, col2 from e
                               )  exs                     
                       );
        update stage 
           set status='success'
         where status is null; 
    end comp_data;
end process_data;   

-- test 
-- populate tables  
insert into e(e_id, col1, col2)  
   select (1,'ABC','def')       from dual union all
   select (2,'No','Not any')    from dual union all      
   select (3,'ok', 'best ever') from dual union all
   select (4,'xx','zzzzzz')     from dual;

insert into stage(e_id, col1, col2)
   select (1,'ABC','def')         from dual union all
   select (2,'No','Not any more') from dual union all
   select (4,'yy', 'zzzzzz')      from dual union all
   select (5,'no e','nnnnn')      from dual;

-- run procedure

begin 
    process_data.comp_date; 
end; 

-- check results
select * from stage;
```

Don't ask. Yes, **you to must list every column** you wish compared in each of the queries involved in the MINUS operation.  
I know the documentation link is old (10gR2), but actually finding Oracle documentation is a royal pain. But the MINUS operator still functions the same in 19c;

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention that the input will come from ICS api as collection.So at my end there is only one table i.e. In your example 'STAGE' table. So basically here comparison is needed between input collection records with STAGE table records. And also it should be identified which column value is mismatched. if in case multiple column value are mismatched then need to update first mismatched column name in REASON.

Comment: Will it be good if i store the collection records into a temp table then compare using minus? But still we can't identify which column value is not matched.

Comment: I've revised the answer. It uses your input array but does so as a table with the MINUS statement.